# Entity Framework - how to seed test data to entities that use table-per-type inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type, seeding

I'm using EF5 code-first, migrations and table-per-type inheritance. I have some classes that inherit from other classes. For example `Tenant` and `Landlord` inherit from `UserProfile`.

I'm using the `protected override void Seed()` method to add test data to my database. So, for example, I create 2 `UserProfile` objects and 1 `Tenant` and 1 `Landlord`. How do I make sure that the tenant entity is associated to the first user profile entity and the landlord entity is associated with the second user profile entity? Because I'm using table-per-type inheritance do I need to explicitly say that the `UserId` of a derived class is equal to the `UserId` of its base class? I've searched around but couldn't find anything of use. I've tried to do it as follows:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        var users = new List<UserProfile>
        {
             new UserProfile { UserId=1, UserName="Matt", Email="a@a.com", AccountType=AccountType.Tenant },
             new UserProfile { UserId=2, UserName="Dave", Email="a@a.com", AccountType=AccountType.Landlord }
        };
        users.ForEach(u => context.UserProfile.AddOrUpdate(u));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var tenants = new List<Tenant>
        {
            new Tenant { UserId = users.Single(x => x.UserId = 1) /* other properties */  }
            // ...
        };
        tenants.ForEach(t => context.Tenant.AddOrUpdate(t));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var landlords = new List<Landlord>
        {
            new Landlord { UserId = users.Single(x => x.UserId = 2) /* other properties */ }
            // ...
        };
        landlords.ForEach(l => context.Tenant.AddOrUpdate(l));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: If "Matt" is a `Tenant` you've got to create it as `Tenant`, not as `UserProfile`. That's the whole point of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the DbContext to load the entity you want to assign to it.

This should do it:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        var users = new List<UserProfile>
    {
         new UserProfile { UserId=1, UserName="Matt", Email="a@a.com", AccountType=AccountType.Tenant },
         new UserProfile { UserId=2, UserName="Dave", Email="a@a.com", AccountType=AccountType.Landlord }
    };
        users.ForEach(u => context.UserProfile.AddOrUpdate(u));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var tenants = new List<Tenant>
    {
        new Tenant { UserId = users.Single(x => x.UserId = context.UserProfile.First(x=>x.UserId = 1)) /* other properties */  }
        // ...
    };
        tenants.ForEach(t => context.Tenant.AddOrUpdate(t));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var landlords = new List<Landlord>
    {
        new Landlord { UserId = users.Single(x => x.UserId = context.UserProfile.First(x=>x.UserId = 2)) /* other properties */ }
        // ...
    };
        landlords.ForEach(l => context.Tenant.AddOrUpdate(l));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While Maximc has the right idea, I found that you can use the `DbContext.Set<T>` method to make use of the `AddOrUpdate` method for your subclasses without having to manually fetch them from the database first:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
{            
    context.Set<Tenant>().AddOrUpdate(
        t => t.UserName, // or whatever property you want to use as an identifier for duplicates
        new Tenant { UserId=1, UserName="Matt", Email="a@a.com" });

    context.Set<Landlord>().AddOrUpdate(
        t => t.UserName,
        new Tenant { UserId=2, UserName="Dave", Email="a@a.com" });
}
```

Also, you probably should not specify the discriminator (in your case AccountType) yourself. Entity Framework will handle that for you in the background when you correctly set up the POCO inheritance.